# Recreate flyway migration table

Tags: java, postgresql, flyway

Is there a way to tell flyway to recreate the flyway-table without applying the migrations. Eg, look into the migration-folder for scripts and assume that they all have been applied and simply make sure that the flyway table contains all of them.

Our scenario is that we are not allowed to run flyway in production and for (ISO;Banking;certifications) reasons. The rules says that we need to remove the tables completely. So when we reset our test-environments from a copy of production we need to recreate the flyway-table. Now we are copy and pasting from an existing test-environment but sometime that isn't in sync with production and all kind of problems occur.

So, we would like to setup our production-copy with the same version as in production and then recreate the tables from that making sure that everything are in sync. But to my understanding the repair-option in flyway doesn't recreate the non-applied scripts...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're describing is called a baseline:

You tell flyway that the database you're working on is at a version number so all scripts previous to this version will be ignored during migrations.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/baseline